# switch to meanjs 0.3 from 0.4

Tags: meanjs

I am trying switch from meanjs 0.4 version to meanjs 0.3 version with the following commmand,

> npm install meanjs/generator-meanjs#0.3

This command is giving error "npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 0.3: fatal: ambiguous argument '0.3': unknown revision or path not in the working tree."

How to switch back to meanjs 0.3 version from meanjs 0.4 version?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to have one version and automatically update to another using the generator.

You have to choose one version and adapt it according to your needs.

The best way to get a MEAN.js project and start working on it, is by cloning the official MEAN.js github repository.

To get the latest version (in master branch):

```
git clone https://github.com/meanjs/mean.git meanjs
```

To get 0.3.3 version:

```
git clone https://github.com/meanjs/mean.git --branch v0.3.3 --single-branch meanjs
```