# generator-meanjs for 0.3 version

Tags: yeoman, mean-stack, crud, meanjs, yeoman-generator

I recently started learning mean.js an all tutorials that I find are for the 0.3.* version, I installed the official yeoman generator and it uses the 0.4.* version, I understand how the new folder distribucion works so there is no problem following the tutorials until I have to generate the scaffold with CRUD, the problem is that generates with the new distribution.

I found here [switch to meanjs 0.3 from 0.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33190467/switch-to-meanjs-0-3-from-0-4) the last repository for 0.3.* version, how can I run CRUD for this version?

Answer (score 0):

You should install the **0.1.12** of **generator-meanjs** which has yoeman's generator for meanjs 0.3

```
npm install -g generator-meanjs@0.1.12
```